# Symfony2 with ISPConfig 3 and Nginx

Tags: symfony, nginx

I want to run a symfony2 app on an subdomin with ISPConfig 3 and nginx

The domain looks like control.domain.tld and the symfony app is located at /var/www/domain.tld/web/control

I just can't figure out what redirect type I need for the subdomain and what nginx Directives.

I've tried it now for hours and always have errors....

What setting do I need the run it?